# Burnside ring for $G$-vector spaces?

Tags: vector-spaces, representation-theory, group-actions

It's known that the Burnside ring is the Grothendieck group of a category of $G$-sets, that must be an abelian monoid, but does exist a similar version of the Burnside ring for $G$-vector spaces?

**To clarify:**

By $G$-vector space I mean a $K$-vector spaces where $G$ acts.

Comment: Sure, the (real or complex) representation ring of $G$.

Comment: Thank you, Dr. May. Can you tell me references to read about it please?

Comment: Wikipedia, ok? :)

Comment: Ok, googling right now :)

Comment: What is the difference between the "new part" and the original question?

Comment: $G$-vector space could be confused with a vector space where the elements come from $G$. Is better quit it?

Comment: Ah, so you were just clarifying.  I think the original statement was clear enough, but it's fine to clarify (just make it clear that you are clarifying rather than adding a new different question).

Comment: Done, thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there's no obstruction to making a similar definition for $G$-vector spaces.  The ring you get (if you restrict to finite-dimensional vector spaces) is called the [representation ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_ring) of $G$ (over $K$).  To be clear, the isomorphism classes of finite-dimensional $G$-vector spaces form a semiring, with addition given by direct sum and multiplication given by tensor product.  The representation ring is then obtained by formally adjoining additive inverses.

Comment: But with your answer is clear that there is not opportunity of confuse.